# Pointer Arithmetic on structs

Tags: c++, c, pointers, memory-management

I was studying some **C** code, when i came across following snippet:

```
struct example *example_clone(struct example *ex)
{  
    struct example *new_ex;  
    new_ex = ex + 1;    // How does this works ?    
    ....  
    new_ex = some_func(...);  //makes new_ex as struct example
    ....  
}
```

Now considering `new_ex = ex + 1;`
Is new_ex just after the `ex` in memory ?
What if some other object exist after `ex` in memory. Is it replaced ?

Comment: With pointer arithmetic the `+1` means `+ sizeof(struct example)`.

Comment: If the input pointer `ex` points to an array of structs, then `ex+1` points to the next struct in the array. But if `ex` points to a single struct, then `ex+1` doesn't point to anything useful.

Comment: `new_ex = ex + 1;` meant `new_ex = &ex[1];`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function is meant to be called with an array of `struct example` objects.

For example:

```
struct example bla[2] = { /* initializers */ };

example_clone(bla);  // OK, bla[1] will be overwritten
```

This is OK as `ex + 1` points to an existing object.

But passing a pointer to an object not an element of an array is not OK:

```
struct example blo = { /* initializers */ };

example_clone(&blo);  // Not OK, the object at &blo + 1 will be overwritten
```

This is not OK as `ex + 1` does not point to an existing object. The function execution will invoke undefined behavior.

Answer (score 2):

Adding `1` to a pointer means *point to the next element*`.   Remember that pointers point to an object of a certain type (they are not just numbered memory locations).

For example if you are pointing at the first car in a car yard, then doing `+1` means you point to the second car.

If there is actually no other object there then that is fine, C has a special case that you are allowed to point one past the end of an existing object. But if you did `+1` again that would cause undefined behaviour.

If you try to read through that pointer and there is no object there, it causes undefined behaviour. You can write through the pointer so long as you are writing into memory that is allocated to you.

Answer (score 2):

> Is `new_ex` just after the `ex` in memory?

Yes.  It points to the memory address just past the end of `ex`.

> What if some other object exist after ex in memory. Is it replaced ?

One of 2 things will happen.  First, it could overwrite the object that is there.  Second, it could segfault if that memory is unavailable.  For this reason, I would consider this function, as is, dangerous.  I would manually inline this code, so that you can verify the contents/existence of `ex + 1`.